# Django ReportLab: using Drawing object to create PDF and return via Httpresponse

Tags: python, django, canvas, httpresponse, reportlab

In ReportLab, Drawing object can be written into different renderers, e.g

```
d = shapes.Drawing(400, 400)
renderPDF.drawToFile(d, 'test.pdf')
```

and in Django, Canvas object can be sent via httpresponse, e.g.:

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=test.pdf'
c = canvas.Canvas(response)
```

in my case, my problem is that I have a reportLab script using Drawing object which saves to local file system. I now put it in Django views, and wondering whether there is a way to not save to local file system but instead sent back to client.

I hope I describe this question clearly.

Thanks for any advice!

**updates**

it turns out there is a function in renderPDF:

```
renderPDF.draw(drawing, canvas, x, y)
```

which can render drawing() object in the given canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it turns out there is a function in renderPDF:

renderPDF.draw(drawing, canvas, x, y)
which can render drawing() object in the given canvas.

Answer (score 6):

Using ReportLab in Django without saving to disk is actually pretty easy. There are even examples in the DjangoDocs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf)

The trick basically boils down to using a "file like object" instead of an actual file. Most people use StringIO for this.

You could do it pretty simply with

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

def some_view(request):
    filename = 'test.pdf'

    # Make your response and prep to attach
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.pdf' % (filename)
    tmp = StringIO()

    # Create a canvas to write on
    p = canvas.Canvas(tmp)
    # With someone on
    p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world")

    # Close the PDF object cleanly.
    p.showPage()
    p.save()

    # Get the data out and close the buffer cleanly
    pdf = tmp.getvalue()
    tmp.close()

    # Get StringIO's body and write it out to the response.
    response.write(pdf)
    return response
```

Comment: thanks! but i think you misunderstood my question, or I didnt say very clearly. I know how to do this using Canvas object, i am looking for a way to put Drawing() object in httpresponse.

Comment: so can I understand the sample you gave as: d = Drawing(400, 400), and then: pdf = buffer.getvalue() buffer.close(), and finally: response.write(pdf)?

Comment: it doesn't work with Drawing(). canvas is fine. in your example, there is a typo: buffer <-> tmp

Answer (score 1):

Drawing has a method called asString with a one required attribute that represents the required drawing format such as 'png', 'gif' or 'jpg'.
so instead of calling

```
renderPDF.drawToFile(d, 'test.pdf')
```

You could call

```
binaryStuff = d.asString('gif')
return HttpResponse(binaryStuff, 'image/gif')
```

Without the need to save your drawing to the disc.

Check https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Charts for full example.