# django: serve dynamic (reportlab) png to template

Tags: django, image, dynamic, reportlab

I've spent the day on this issue with no success so help would be appreciated.

I generate a graph using reportlab and successfully render it to the browser using this [tutorial](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Charts):

```
        d = MyBarChartDrawing()

        #extract the request params of interest.
        #I suggest having a default for everything.
        if 'height' in request:
            d.height = int(request['height'])
        if 'width' in request:
            d.width = int(request['width'])

        if 'numbers' in request:
            strNumbers = request['numbers']
            numbers = map(int, strNumbers.split(','))    
            d.chart.data = [numbers]   #bar charts take a list-of-lists for data

        if 'title' in request:
            d.title.text = request['title']


        #get a GIF (or PNG, JPG, or whatever)
        binaryStuff = d.asString('png')

        return HttpResponse(binaryStuff, 'image/png')
```

My issue though is that I'd like to render this png within a template, like so (does not work):

```
return render(request, "subscription/monitorSizes.html", {'form':form,'message':'','graph':binaryStuff})
```

I've been hacking away at this issue for ages. It's no doubt a newbie problem!  To save my sanity, would appreciate advice on this.  Many thanks :)

edit: I found another [stackoverflow Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184329/insert-reportlab-chart-into-django-template?rq=1) on the same issue but it was not really solved.

Comment: Could you not call the img generation view as a url as a src in a img tag so you return as return HttpResponse(binaryStuff, 'image/png')? rather then trying to pass binaryStuff?

Comment: tried that.  In my template:{% if graph != '' %}
<img src="{{ graph }}"  alt="some_text">
{% endif %}

Comment: i meant <img src="{% url your_app.views.get_image var1 var2 %}"/> where get_image is the view you show above, it that what you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In views.py

```
def show_image(request):
    d = MyBarChartDrawing()
    #extract the request params of interest.
    #I suggest having a default for everything.
    if 'height' in request:
        d.height = int(request['height'])
    if 'width' in request:
        d.width = int(request['width'])

    if 'numbers' in request:
        strNumbers = request['numbers']
        numbers = map(int, strNumbers.split(','))    
        d.chart.data = [numbers]   #bar charts take a list-of-lists for data

    if 'title' in request:
        d.title.text = request['title']


    #get a GIF (or PNG, JPG, or whatever)
    binaryStuff = d.asString('png')

    return HttpResponse(binaryStuff, 'image/png')

def somepage(request):
     return render(request, "subscription/monitorSizes.html", {'form':form,'message':'','graph':reverse('show_image')})
```

In urls.py

```
...
url(r'^show_image/$', 'your_view.show_image', name='show_image'),
url(r'^somepage/$', 'your_view.somepage', name='somepage'),
...
```

In subscription/monitorSizes.html

```
...
{% if graph != '' %} <img src="{{ graph }}" alt="some_text"> {% endif %}
...
```