# How to view dynamically generated svg image in template using <img> html tag (Django)?

Tags: python, html, django, svg, django-templates

I have a url linked to a view that returns an image (successfully).
I am trying to use this url as a value of `<img>` tag `src` attribute inside template html file.

urls.py

```
url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
url(r'^image/(?P<graph_name>[a-zA-z]+)$', views.dynamic_image, name='dynamic-image'),    
)
```

views.py

```
def dynamic_image(request, graph_name):
    image=functionToCreateImage(graph_name)
    return HttpResponse(image, content_type="image/svg+xml")

def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('graphs/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'gene_links_graph':reverse('dynamic-image', args=['gene_links_graph'])})
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

index.html

```
...
<a href = "{{ gene_links_graph }}">
    <img scr="{{ gene_links_graph }}" alt="img1">
</a>
...
```

The image renders on a new page via link, but does not appear on `index.html` page. How to fix that?

**upd** rendered html page source

```
<a href = "/graphs/image/gene_links_graph/">
    <img scr="/graphs/image/gene_links_graph/" alt="img1">
</a>
```

There is a similar thread, but it didn't work in my case
[django: serve dynamic (reportlab) png to template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358091/django-serve-dynamic-reportlab-png-to-template)

Comment: what does index.html rendered text look like? (display source in browser)

Comment: just updated. there `href` works while `img` does not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is the generated HTML `<img scr="">` instead of `<img src="">`?  Could that be your problem?

Comment: Yeah! This was the case! Thanks and sorry for such a stupid question :)